# Return annotated queryset against graphql queries on django graphene

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, django-annotate

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=189)

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=189)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name="customers")

class Message(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="messages")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I am using the following queryset to get all customers under a certain project ordered by who had messaged last.

```
qs = Customer.objects.filter(messages__isnull=False) \
.annotate(last_message=Max('messages__created_at')).order_by('-last_message')
```

Now I want to use a basic graphene query (NOT relay) to get a project and the customers associated with this project according to the annotated queryset.
I may also have a second use-case where I would need to filter the project.customers.all() queryset according to a field in the Customer table (e.g. the customers which have is_deleted=False).

Currently in my graphql schema i have,

```
class ProjectNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Project

class CustomerNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    project = graphene.Field(ProjectNode, id=graphene.Int(), token=graphene.String(), )
    top_chat_customers = graphene.Field(CustomerNode, project_id=graphene.Int())

     def resolve_project(self, info, **kwargs):
        pk = kwargs["id"]
        return Project.objects.filter(id=pk).first()

    def resolve_top_chat_customers(self, info, **kwargs):
        project = Project.objects.filter(id=kwargs["project_id"]).first()
        return Customer.objects.filter(project=project, messages__isnull=False) \
.annotate(last_message=Max('messages__created_at')).order_by('-last_message')
```

Here when I try to get the list of customers separately by providing the project Id, It shows error: "Received incompatible instance..."

Any ideas on how I should get the list of customers from within the project node and as a separate top_chat_customers query?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `resolve_top_chat_customers` returns an iterable queryset, and not an individual `Customer` object, so in `Query` you need to specify that you're returning a list:

```
top_chat_customers = graphene.List(CustomerNode, project_id=graphene.Int())
```

Also, any annotated fields from the query aren't going to be part of the schema automatically.  If you want to see them you'd need to add them explicitly:

```
class CustomerNode(DjangoObjectType):
    last_message = graphene.String()

    class Meta:
        model = Customer

    def resolve_last_message(self, info):
        # Returns last message only if the object was annotated
        return getattr(self, 'last_message', None)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had already noticed the graphene.List problem you mentioned but couldn't find solution for annotating.

Comment: Also, is there any way for a query to return two different Objects (e.g ProjectNode and CustomerNode). What I want to say is, can I get all Customers under a project with the annotated field?

Comment: using a prefetch_related with a custom Prefetch to customise the Customer queryset to annotate did the trick! Thank you for the help!